# Laravel 5 Call to a member function from model to controller on null

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm still learning to understand the foundation. 
I was trying to call a function from model to controller but it returns on null.
I have a query in **Scanclient.php** and I need to return the results to the **ScanclientController.php** but yeah it returns on null

My model and controller looks like this:

Model: **ScanClient.php**

```
public function uniqueVisitsPerday()
    {

        $query = DB::table('scan_clients')->select('device_id as deviceId', 'created_at_date as visitDate');

       $items = $query->addSelect(DB::raw('count(DISTINCT address) as uniqueVisitsPerDay'))
           ->whereIn('device_id', [4, 6, 7])
           ->groupBy('device_id','created_at_date')
           ->orderBy('created_at_date', 'asc')
           ->get();

      return $items;
    }
```

Controller: **ScanclientController.php**

```
public function uniqueVisits()
    {        

        dd($this->ScanClient->uniqueVisitsPerDay()->get());

    }
```

It would be nice if you guys can help. Thanks a lot!

Comment: you have already returned the data so you dont need `get()` here `$this->ScanClient->uniqueVisitsPerDay()->get();`, try `dd($this->ScanClient->uniqueVisitsPerDay());`

Comment: @Regolithi I have tried that before but it returns null also